# Do we accept edits which translate questions (and maybe answers?)

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, english

I was clicking through the Suggested edits review queue and I found this suggested edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7896393

A new user posts a question in Spanish (I think?) and another user translated the question. Regardless, if the translated question is fine: is this a behaviour we want?

Should people translate questions into English? I mean, I have no chance to check, if the translation is correct and have to skip this review.

Comment: Translating a question into English so that users can properly understand and answer the question sounds like a good thing.

Comment: We definitely want this as long as they are being translated properly. If you don't know then skipping is the appropriate action and hopefully someone else will know or the OP will approve it if it seems correct to them. I usually leave a comment that it should be in English and sometimes vote to close as unclear

Comment: @JoeW If the OP wrote the question in a different language, it's quite likely they won't understand any answer given in English. Translating the question is actually a _bad_ idea in that case, as the OP cannot answer clarifying questions or understand the answers to their questions. Better to let them know, as a commenter already has, that the site is English only and close the question.

Answer (score 6):

I feel iffy about edits like this.  It *could* be the case that the translation is correct, and it doesn't take much effort to feed one of those translations into Google Translate to be sure that nothing untoward was inserted in.

The real problem is that the site is and has always been English only (but there *are* a number of foreign language Stack Overflows out there, like Portuguese, Japanese, and Russian).

These sorts of edits I wouldn't approve because I can't be sure if they improved* the question or not.

<sup>*:  In this case, it needs to be improved for the person finding the question, the people answering the question, **and** the OP that asked in the first place.  Translating it to a language they may not fully understand diminishes this.</sup>

Comment: Was writing own answer, you've said most of what I was going to. I do want to add here that there's been somewhat of a prior consensus in posts like [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262054/2474859) that anything non-English is flag-worthy anyway.

Comment: If a question isn't in English then it should either be translated or closed as it wouldn't be helpful in the current state. Also need to remember that someone maybe able to understand English but ask the question in their native language because it is easier for them to explain the issue and they don't understand that this site is English only.