# What would be the appropriate reason to give if rejecting a Suggested Edit of a question translating it from a non-English language?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, languages, english

I understand that translating questions from non-English language into English is discouraged:

> Please do not translate posts for the OP. They need to be able to respond to feedback, and if they cannot themselves translate the post we cannot be certain that they can understand any feedback provided (by comments, answers, or Help Center content). -- [Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/1225882)

So, when reviewing a [Suggested Edit, that does exactly this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20444539), I assume I [should reject the edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291938/do-we-accept-edits-which-translate-questions-and-maybe-answers).

**What, then, would be the appropriate reason to give for rejecting**?

Comment: There is no reason to reject a translation as an edit suggestion.

Comment: @peterh Hm, I gave two sources that, to my interpretation, suggest that it should be rejected. Could you elaborate on why you think that's wrong?

Comment: I'd go with "conflicts with authors intends". The argumentation is not optimal, but the authors intent was to ask a question in language A. Translating it to a language the author might not be able to understand conflicts with what they wanted to do.

Comment: @anothernode Well, your idea is okay, the original one (that translations should be rejected) is a harmful, destructive, antagonistic one, harming others without reason and producing a toxic atmosphere on the site. But if the original idea would be okay, also your suggestion would be okay. So I removed my down. Although the answer is "no such reason is needed", in my opinion, because it doesn't happen enough often for that.

Comment: I've just wrote an answer, it had explained my previous comment. But meanwhile it became clear to me, that it would be so strongly critical against the customs here, that I would risk my account by posting that.

Comment: @peterh I see your point, and I think there's some truth in it, although maybe a bit exaggerated. But on the other hand it's also true that it just doesn't make much sense to use the English Stack Overflow if you cannot understand and articulate yourself in English, does it? Also, I didn't suggest to create a new dedicated reject reason just for this rare case, I just wanted to know what the community thinks would be the most appropriate reject reason to give out of the existing ones.

Comment: @anothernode I am sorry but it seems it is better if we don't talk about it. Maybe I would say something which would result a suspension.

Comment: @peterh "that I would risk my account by posting that" - impossible. Not on meta. You are free to post any answer you want. It might get downvoted into oblivion for sure, but that is a) not damaging to your reputation and b) *very valuable information*. Knowing that something is absolutely hated is just as valuable as knowing that something is very well received. Who knows, you might be surprised.

Comment: @Gimby After some suspension I developed a political intuition, an intuitive feeling, what is the limit what the system yet tolerates. Sometimes I step over it, and I have no way to know, which of my suspension terms will be the last. I have a numerous strongly downvoted posts, both here and on the MSE, and I posted them knowing well, that they will be voted down. There is a limit until I want to risk conflicts. Please don't doubt my decision, it is my account.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would just use the "Causes Harm" reason, which gives you a box to explain your rejection. Then just put in the very "Please do not..." quote from your question. If you recognise the language, perhaps leave a friendly comment directing the OP to the language specific SO (i.e. [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) or [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), etc.) if there is one.

Comment: I accept this answer because I like idea to include a link to a language specific SO into the rejection reason comment, if appropriate.

Comment: A note of warning, though: it often happens that a non-English question on this site is not in conditions for a direct migration to a language specific Stack Overflow. This should only be advised if the question would be salvageable without the language barrier.

Comment: @E_net4 I think that goes without saying, just point the OP there, and that community can help fix up the question. We do it here all the time. And I didn't mention migration, just leave a comment to the effect "you might try this question over here" with the appropriate link

Answer (score 11):

Just select the custom one (called "cause harm") and provide a reason. You don't need to use preexisting ones for those.

Answer (score 5):

If one wanted a logical justification for "Causes harm" (or "Conflicts with Author's intention") it would be this:

- By asking a question in language X, the OP implies that their English skills are not sufficient to ask an intelligible question in English.
- By translating the question into English, you are telling people it is OK to answer in English.  But there is a good chance that the OP won't understand an English answer.
- By translating the question into English, you also risk changing the question's (language independent) meaning.  Even if you are fluent in both the OP's language, and in English.  Why?  Because the OP may not have expressed himself clearly / correctly in his original question.  (How many times have you seen a question from a native English speaker who is unable to express his question accurately ... due to poor understanding of IT terminology, or due to poor writing skills.)

Answer (score -3):

I agree with the first comment by @peterh-ReinstateMonica.

Rejecting a quality translation from someone who cares enough to translate and is adequately skilled to do so seems unnecessarily malicious and unforgiving.

After all, we are all supposed to be curating great content.

We should not be basing the decision to improve or not improve a question based on the notion that the OP may not understand the support received.  After all, let's not forget -- Stack Overflow pages are NEVER merely 1-to-1 interactions.  Questions are the seeds by which bounties of knowledge can be shared with thousands of researchers.

Am I suggesting that all non-English answers *should be* translated by volunteers? No, however, if a volunteers wants to help, let's not stomp on their efforts.

**Approve the edit if it is good and correct**, then inform the OP that they must always post questions in English.  If the edit has any concern that their interpretation may be flawed, they should leave a comment encouraging the OP to re-edit the question to improve accuracy.

Comment: This answer seems "unnecessarily malicious and unforgiving". The FAQ regarding non-English content is clear and on point regarding the reasons translation is discouraged.  "they should leave a comment encouraging the OP to re-edit the question to improve accuracy" - in the original non-English language? Moderators have a hard enough time determining "unfriendly or unkind" in English, now they may have to do so in other languages? Also, we have enough rep hunters out there that if this were to become okay, legions of copy pasta from Google Translate would become the norm. No thanks.

Comment: You lost me at `This answer seems "unnecessarily malicious and unforgiving".`. There is literally nothing malicious about my suggestion that we should permit helpful people to be helpful.

Comment: There is plenty malicious in suggesting that others are being malicious is rejecting edits that will not help the OP or requiring that questioners be able to understand and participate in their own questions.

Comment: The issue is not that the editor may or may not be translating the post correctly, it is that the site is English-only, so OP may not be able to understand things if the post is translated and then an answer is given in English. That is why it remains the author's sole responsibility to ask in English, so we don't have to worry.

Comment: Again, there is too much focus on the OP's ability.  Stack Overflow pages aim to serve thousands of researchers.  The OP is only one of the people who may benefit.

Comment: The author seems to always be the focus on a new post. If they do not show effort, it's closed, despite that it could serve lots of people and already have good Answers. The site is moving away from evaluating content already.

Comment: @Scratte I disagree. People don't have to show any effort from what I can tell. There have been many answers on Meta about the fact that there is no close reason for lack of effort. Spend some time in the more popular tags like [javascript]. You'll find plenty of no-effort, no-research questions that get upvotes and answers within minutes.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I sit in the Triage queue, and I monitor what goes on there.. at present users are getting review suspended if they pick "Looks OK" on a clear and focused post if it doesn't show research effort. The irony of is that every time I need an Answer or want to know how to do something, I search and always land on some low-effort Question with lots of great Answers.